# "java.lang.AssertionError: APK bundle must contain the expected embedded asset index.android.bundle" error whe building using expo version 6.0.5

Tags: android, react-native, expo

As the title says I get this error:

```
"java.lang.AssertionError: APK bundle must contain the expected embedded asset index.android.bundle"
```

After building using the latest expo CLI version. When i download my app from google store it crashes but it works fine in local dev mode using expo, so i have no clue what is going on.

Just in case this is package.json

```
{
  "name": "dnd",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.12",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.5",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.5",
    "expo": "~46.0.8",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.4",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-text-size": "^4.0.0-rc.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.0",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.69.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

And this is the app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Hoja de personaje 3.5e",
    "slug": "Hojadepersonaje35e",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "owner": "calvix1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/appIcon.jpg",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.calvix1.hojadepersonaje35e",
      "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode":"pan",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/appIcon.jpg",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "versionCode":3
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

The app is built using Expo sdk 46.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue. I had recently upgraded from Expo SDK 45 to Expo SDK 46 on a bare project.

I had to use the react-native upgrade helper (https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.68.2&to=0.69.5) to identify the expected version for gradle and some other dependencies.

In `android/build.gradle` I changed:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4')
classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
classpath('de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2')
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1')
classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
classpath('de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1')
```

This gave me some hints: [index.android.bundle missing in APK after upgrading to RN 0.68](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71847922/index-android-bundle-missing-in-apk-after-upgrading-to-rn-0-68)

Comment: This was really helpful! Almost spent 4 days around this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Expo SDK 47, I resolved my problem updating my eas-cli to the latest version.

I was using the version 0.54 and I updated to 3.5.2

I had problems updating this, so I used Yarn to build:

```
yarn add global eas-cli
yarn eas build --profile production
```

and worked fine!